# AWS Redshift - Kinesis Data streams - data transformation

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis

As a part of our architecture, we are having Kinesis streams which will send data streams to Redshift, the current thought process is to create external external schema on top of the Kinesis streams and then use materialized views to persist the data with minimal transformations as needed.

However In addition to this there is a need to perform a series of transformations (which are quite complex) on this data and  load it into target tables. Was thinking about using stored procedures to perform these transformations and load into a target table. So the flow is like Kinesis Streams -> External View (Real time) -> Batch Processing (Materialized view and stored procedure).

To call the stored procedures (SP) on a timely schedule, the thought process was to schedule the SQL queries. Being fairly new to AWS Redshift and the Kinesis streaming ingestion and exploring on the available options, would like to get thoughts on the above approach.

Further understand that there are limitations with stored procedures, (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-constraints.html) and scheduling of SQL queries might not give the feasibility of implementing a good orchestration flow. Hence would like to understand alternate methods that are available to implement the above specifically post the availability of data in external view.

Comment: Kinesis Data Firehose may be a better fit for your use case. With Kinesis Data Firehose, you can consume from a Kinesis stream, transform the data via Lambda, and then sink to Redshift. Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html

Comment: One of the consideration from an architectural view point is to use the Kinesis Data Stream -> Redshift out-of-the box integration to load data into redshift (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/02/amazon-redshift-public-preview-streaming-ingestion-kinesis-data-streams/ ).

Hence Kinesis firehose, will bring in additional processing layer (and cost) to the solution, if my understanding is correct. However would like to understand any key advantages of this approach over SP based approach.

Further any key dis-advantages of the SP based approach as mentioned above.

Comment: Depending on how complex the transformations are, Lambda may be a better fit. If the transformation logic can be developed, tested, and monitored easily with stored procedures, then ok.